# Nested Loops to Calculate Factorial without Multiplication

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out a C program that calculates a factorial using nested while loops with no multiplication. Is there an easy way to do this with as little variables as possible?

I have an inner loop that does multiplication using addition, but I can't seem to find an outer loop that would then find the factorial.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    unsigned int a = 4;
    unsigned int b = 4;
    unsigned int c = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while(i < b) {
        c += a;
        i++;
    }

    printf("Result: %u", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this for turning the code later into assembly? I ask because I am pretty sure that I recently saw practically the same question.

Comment: Please learn about indentation, and formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: [Hide the loops in functions](https://ideone.com/oWAVJh) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one solution for that :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mult (int n1, int n2);

int main () {
    int number,result,count;
    scanf("%d",&number);
    result=number;
    for (count=number-1;count>1;count--)
        result=mult(result,count);
    printf ("factorial is %d",result);
    return 0;
}

int mult (int n1, int n2) {
    int i,answer=0;
    for (i=1;i<=n2;i++)
        answer+=n1;
    return answer;
}
```

I used my own variable names but that shouldn't be a problem.